# Managing multiple PowerShell prompts

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

If I have multiple Powershell Prompts to different machines, it can get confusing.  While, the command prompts all show the machine I am at, I was trying to find a solution that changed the titlebar to the machine I'm hooked up.

Or I am open to any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- One way to do this, if you don't have a ton of servers to manage, is to [change the background of your PowerShell console for different servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156814.aspx). I usually do this for user account management, i.e. a PS console launched as a normal user is blue and an admin console has a red background. It gets impractical if you have more than five or six servers, though.
- You could make the prompt reflect the hostname of the server you're on. Check out some concepts behind changing PowerShell prompts [here](http://mshforfun.blogspot.com/2006/05/perfect-prompt-for-windows-powershell.html) and [here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/04/26/the-story-behind-the-naming-and-location-of-powershell-profiles/). Why user@hostname isn't in the default prompt for PowerShell is beyond me.
- You may be interested in the "[PowerCMD](http://www.powercmd.com/)" utility.

Comment: Yeah, I need to get to reading.  On another note, the random animals OReily chooses has always cracked me up.

Answer (score 2):

you can set the shell window title with `$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Eat at Joe's"`